# Do film emulation presets assume a certain white balance setting?

Tags: post-processing, film, white-balance, digital-vs-film

The other day I thought I'd try *'shooting a specific film'*, i.e., post-process all the shots from the day with one particular film emulation preset, Kodak Portra 160 in this case.  But when I sat down to process my shots I wondered if it mattered if it was important to manually set the WB to 'daylight' since Portra 160 is a 'daylight' film.

I first set my shots to 5500 (~ daylight) and then ran the preset, the results were not what I would expect from Portra 160 in the same lighting.  The shots were from my back yard with relatively afternoon cool lighting and I've shot *actual* Portra 160 in this same situation.

Is my assumption incorrect in that I should set the WB to 'daylight'? Do film emulation presets take some WB into account. In this case, I'm using the [VSCO film emulation presets](http://vsco.co/film).

Luckily I shot some Portra 160 and some digital shots of the same scene a while back, here are the results:

[image]

As you can see, setting the WB to Daylight resulted in a cooler photograph than if I set it to Auto compared to actual Portra 160.

Comment: I also use and love Portra (although I prefer the 400). I'd be curious to see your results with the preset along with different white balance selections.

Comment: You're right, I need to post some examples, will do!

Comment: \*cough\* \*cough\*

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in your expectation that the Portra film shots are going to strongly show the effects of different color temperatures.

While it's true that Portra 160 (or any commonly-available color film these days) is daylight balanced, color prints and scans of color negatives are always color corrected as part of the process. The photo you're trying to match has already had the white balance "fixed" by the person printing or scanning the film.

If you shot reversal film (for transparencies or slides) your expectation would be more accurate, since there's no correction applied after the photo is taken.

Comment: Ah, hrmph, I'll have to go look back at my scans and see if thats the case in the software too.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I think so. It seems like you may have applied the same bias to the RAW data twice. What were your results when you combined "Auto WB" with the emulation preset? Also, depending on your RAW convertor "Daylight" doesn't always exactly equate to 5500°K, 5200°K, or any other particular temperature as there is sometimes some compensation on the magenta/green axis as well as the blue/amber (color temperature) axis.

Comment: What do you mean by "It seems like you may have applied the same bias to the RAW data twice."?

Comment: I mean it appears the light at the time you shot was higher than 6700°K but you set the WB @ 5500°K, so you had already applied a fairly significant offset *before* you applied the results of the Porta 160 preset. The preset then applied additional WB offset because it likely assumed the photo was taken using either *Auto WB* or a WB set to the actual temperature of the light.

Comment: _" it likely assumed the photo was taken using either Auto WB or a WB set to the actual temperature of the light"_ I think that is the problem, the preset assumes you shot in daylight WB (or corrected to daylight WB) where _I_ expect it should behave like Portra film which just has a color shift if you're not in Daylight.

Comment: No, I think the presets assume you used Auto WB. And *Daylight* does not always have the same color temperature. If you shoot at 5200°K at high noon, your pictures are going to have a cool cast. If you shoot at 5200°K during the golden hour, your pictures will have a warm cast. That is regardless of whether you are using manual WB set at 5200°K on a digital camera or film balanced for 5200°K.

Comment: Agreed. I would expect if I shoot with actual Portra 160 film, in different color temperatures, to result in different casts, and I'd expect a Portra 160 preset to do those same casts and thats what I _want to happen_.  The problem is, as you see in my image example, the color cast isn't the same as actual Portra 160 film.